# Replacement of operation and constant symbols in a first order theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In First Order Mathematical Logic by Angelo Margaris the axioms of abelian groups (AG) are given as:

AG1. $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((x + y) + z = x + (y + z))$

AG2. $\forall x (x + 0 = x)$

AG3. $\forall x \exists y (x + y = 0)$

AG4. $\forall x \forall y (x + y = y + x)$

He later states that:

Every n-place operation symbol of a first order theory can be replaced by an n + 1-place predicate symbol, and every constant symbol by a 1-place predicate symbol. We illustrate the procedure with AG. Let $G$ be the first 3-place predicate symbol and $H$ be the first 1-place predicate symbol. We replace $+$ by $G$ and $0$ by $H$. $G(r, s, t)$ is interpreted as $r + s = t$, and $H(r)$ is interpreted as $r = 0$. We need the additional axioms

$\forall x \forall y \exists ! z G(x, y, z)$

$\exists ! x H(x)$

Axioms AG2 and AG3 translate into

AG2'. $\forall x \forall y (H(y) \to G(x, y, x))$

AG3'. $\forall x \forall z (H(z) \to \exists y G(x, y, z))$

It is then asked of the reader to give the axioms AG1' and AG4' corresponding to AG1 and AG4, using the predicate symbol $G$ in place of $+$. My attempt is:

AG1'. $\forall x \forall y \forall z ( ( G(x, y, r) \land G(r, z, t) ) \iff ( G(y, z, s) \land G(x, s, t) ) )$

AG4'. $\forall x \forall y ( G(x, y, t) \iff G(y, x, t) )$

Is this correct? How can I verify it? Is there a general algorithm for this procedure? What does it mean to say that this can be done? That is, what exactly are we saying is preserved after replacing the operation and constant symbols in this manner?

EDIT:

Are these correct?

AG1$'$. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall r \forall s \forall t ((G(x, y, r) \land G(y, z, s)) \to (G(r, z, t) \iff G(x, s, t)))$

AG4$'$. $\forall x \forall y \forall t (G(x, y, t) \iff G(y, z, t))$

Comment: You need to bind those free variables. $r$, $s$, and $t$.

Comment: I can believe that, but I'm not sure how they should be bound.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct?

Yes, modulo my comment about the unbound variables.

> How can I verify it?

Show that the class of models of the new theory is also the class of Abelian groups.

> Is there a general algorithm for this procedure?

It's a (repeated application of a) fairly straightforward local transformation. Effectively, all you're doing is naming intermediaries. For example, $R(f(x),g(h(y,z)))$ is clearly equivalent to $R(a,b)\land f(x) = a\land g(c) = b \land h(y,z) = c$. You then replace those equations by the new relation symbols corresponding to the functions: $R(a,b)\land F(x,a)\land G(c, b)\land H(y,z,c)$. Like in your results, I've introduced new unbound variables. How should I bind them? Hint: Function composition is relation composition.

It would be a fairly simple programming exercise to walk over formulas and perform this translation.

> What does it mean to say that this can be done?

At least for the "normal" notion of semantics, this is a reflection of the fact that operations are interpreted as functions and functions can be represented by their graphs. A function $D^n\to D$ is equivalently a subset of $D^n\times D$.

This likely goes far beyond what was intended, but in categorical semantics (as in category theory), we can more or less do the same thing if we consider semantics in categories with finite limits (aka left exact or lex categories). However, the theory of groups can be interpreted into categories with only finite products, so switching from operations to relations constrains the class of models (now considering models beyond set-theoretic ones). Indeed, universal algebra dispenses with relation symbols entirely (leaving only equality) and corresponds to the internal language of categories with finite products.

> That is, what exactly are we saying is preserved after replacing the
>   operation and constant symbols in this manner?

The main thing that is preserved is the class of models.

Comment: How does the algorithm introduce implication?

Comment: @user695931 It doesn't, but you can prove under the assumption that $\exists ! x.H(x)$ that $(\forall x.H(x)\Rightarrow P(x))\equiv(\exists x.H(x)\land P(x))$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure I follow. I was thinking maybe: AG1'. $\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall r \forall s \forall t ( (G(x, y, r) \land G(y, z, s)) \to (G(r, z, t) \iff G(x, s, t)) )$ and AG4': $\forall x \forall y \forall t ( G(x, y, t) \iff G(y, x, t) )$?

Comment: Here's a straightforward way to write the associative law: $$\forall xyzstvw(Gxys\land Gszv\land Gyzt\land Gxtw\implies v=w)$$

Comment: @bof I guess we don't need to replace the equality sign?